# Command Prompt Width Within PHP

Tags: php, powershell, wmi, command-prompt, windows-server

I'm running PHP on a Windows Server and I have a script that uses PowerShell to perform some WMI queries. I'm taking the results of the query and exploding it by line break so that each property of the WMI class is its own line (and later will be used for other stuff).

The problem I'm having is that by default, the command prompt window width is limited to 80 characters so when the PHP script obtains the results of the WMI query, certain lines that exceed 80 characters are broken up into numerous lines and I'd really like each line to only be one line regardless of how long the string is.

I've tried logging into the server and changing the default width of the command prompt as well as both 32- and 64-bit PowerShell windows. When I run the commands directly in those applications, I can see it's no longer breaking on 80 characters. However, my PHP script still does.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
exec("powershell.exe -Command \" & { Get-WmiObject -Query 'Select * From Win32OperatingSystem' | Format-List *} \" ", $Output, $ReturnValue);

foreach ($Output as $PSOutput) {

    $ExplodePSOutput = explode("\r\n", $PSOutput);

    foreach ($ExplodePSOutput as $WMIProperty) {
        echo $WMIProperty."<br>";
    }
}
```

Here's an example of what the output is like:

```
Status : OK
Name : Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|C:\
WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition
2
FreePhysicalMemory : 9224968
```

But I'm wanting it to look like this:

```
Status : OK
Name : Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2
FreePhysicalMemory : 9224968
```

**Update**:

My ultimate goal was to extract each property name from the selected WMI class. Since each property named was followed with " : ", I was able to work around this problem by searching each exploded string for this pattern and returning the value to the left of that. If that pattern doesn't exist, it's presumably a line that was broken because it went over the 80 character limit.

```
$PatternPosition = strpos($WMIPropertyResult, " : ");
$WMIPropertyName = substr($WMIPropertyResult, 0, $PatternPosition);
```

PowerShell formats the output to align all of the property values but it formats it based on the longest property name and property names will obviously change based on what WMI class is being queried. So it makes more sense to search for the " : " pattern instead of hardcoding a value in the substr() function.

I'll leave this post around in case anyone has a suggestion on the original question but for my use case, I believe I have a sufficient workaround.